# Running totals in Matrix form

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvoZu.png)

I am getting output like in image 1 but i am expecting the output as it is in image2. Could you please help me to get using sql.

Comment: YEAR STATUS Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun July Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2003 New 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 7 76 300 99 23
2003 Lost 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
2003 Total 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 7 76 300 97 23
2004 New 4 28 16 16 13 8 14 13 10 4 5 3
2004 Lost 0 6 9 10 5 8 3 8 12 4 6 8
2004 Total 4 22 7 6 8 0 11 5 -2 0 -1 -5

Comment: What is image 1 and 2 ? I only see one single image

Comment: Also, you need to specify what the data source looks like and what query are you using to "_get the output_".